# 401 unauthorized with SSL and HttpClient library

Tags: java, apache, ssl, httpclient

When i try to login app with ssl

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[]{"TLSv1"},
            null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://otherwebapp.my.com/login");
        BasicCredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I get 401 Unauthorized

When i login by POST in Chrome Advanced Rest Client view
everything works well.

I was looking differences through Wireshark monitor traffic

and not found difference between sending  of  my code and of chrome Advanced Rest Client view

If someone has ideas, plz help me

Comment: I see the exact same thing whether I'm using the TrustSelfSignedStrategy or loading keys from my key store and using those.  In the latter case, the certificate passes validation and I see the NTLM (I'm using NTCredentials) dance going on but it ultimately still spits out 401.